# About jQuery after

Tags: jquery, ajax

Suppose my HTML input looks like this :

```
<input type="text" class="hello">
```

I used jQuery and inserted element after it like this. AND it uses ajax

```
$(".hello").after("<p>"+response."</p>"); //response means things that come from ajax.
```

But after creates new element `"<p>"+response."</p>"` on every response...

How do I insert element jQuery class `.hello` so it get updated according to ajax instead of inserting `"<p>"+response."</p>"..`

I don't have any idea how to do it . :(

Regards

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean that you want to set the value of the `input`, or that you only want one response to appear after the element, or something else entirely...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I want to set value after the element .hello but jqeury .after will insert new element every time so i want to update it instead of inserting every time .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
//find the next element of .hello
var $p = $(".hello").next();
//if it is not a p element
if (!$p.is('p')) {
    //create a new p element and insert it after .hello
    $p = $('<p />').insertAfter('.hello');
}
//update its text
$p.text(response)
```

Comment: How do i set class to that p element?

Comment: @quersfas you can change to `$('<p />', {className: 'some-class'}).insertAfter('.hello');`

Comment: Thanks...but it creating problem when there is p element already isn't it??

Comment: @quersfas... yes.. it will create a problem if the next sibling of `.hello` is a `p` element... you can add a class to the new `p` element and use that to fix the problem... like `if (!$p.is('p.response')) {` then `$('<p />', {className: 'response'}).insertAfter('.hello');`

Answer (score 0):

Given the description in your comment, it would be best to have a containing element which holds the response. You can then just overwrite its HTML on each request.

```
<input type="text" class="hello">
<p class="response-container"></p>
```

```js
// in your AJAX success handler...
$(".hello").next('.response-container').html(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to have previously that response element o create just once.

```
<p class=".helloResponse">response</p>
<input type="text" class="hello">

$(".helloResponse").html(response);
```

Another way is to create the element first, but just once.

```
if($(".helloResponse").length ==0) {
$(".hello").after("<p class='helloResponse'>"+response +"</p>");
} else {
$(".helloResponse").html(response);
}
```

Comment: .after("<p class="helloResponse">"+response."</p>");

quote inside quote causing error man :(

Comment: Sorry I just copy that part from your question, I update the answer.